# Hide Light DOM (Nested Elements) on Web Components While Waiting for Slot Absorption to Prevent Flashing Temporary Rendering of Content

Tags: javascript, css, web-component, shadow-dom, native-web-component

I want to prevent showing light DOM content while it's waiting to be absorbed into a `<slot>`.  I've tried many workarounds.

Here's my use case:

```html
<custom-select>
  <custom-option>One</custom-option>
  <custom-option>Two</custom-option>
  <custom-option>Three</custom-option>
</custom-select>
```

Both types of elements have a default `<slot></slot>` for the light DOM (nested content).

When the page loads, I see the raw text "One", "Two", and "Three" for however long it takes for the page to load (it's very obvious on heavy page loads), and then everything is absorbed into their `<slot>`s and is hidden as expected.

I've tried `:host` and `:host` children hiding, hiding by default and then adding a class to show it, and other dynamic things like that. Not even doing `this.style.display = 'none';` *before* attaching the `shadowRoot` in the `constructor` works!  Crazy stuff.  All styling happens after it's rendered to the DOM regardless of how styling is implemented.

Is there not a simple solution that will hide it immediately (and ideally always hide the light DOM and allow the showing of the light DOM in the slot)?

I do NOT want an external stylesheet controlling this, though that accomplishes the ultimate need (i.e., hiding an custom element, and then the custom element adds a class later that allows the CSS to show it).  The point is to let components do their thing, not control a nuance--externally defeating the whole purpose of componentized elements and their micro DOMs.

Comment: Execute your ``customElements.define`` **before** DOM is created. And use the ``:defined`` pseudo selector.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Though that doesn't isolate the concern within the components themselves which is what I was looking for, those two things function.  Specifically making sure they are loaded before the DOM's <body> is created, and adding this style in the <head> <style> of `custom-option:not(:defined) { display: none; }`.  I suppose I could accept that native components sometimes need external CSS registering, and not just the script registering of the components themselves.  If there is not component-only way to address this shortly, please post this answer noting it's external though.

Comment: Also see: https://www.jacobmilhorn.com/posts/solving-fouc-in-web-components/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas, there is no way to completely prevent FOUC from loading a style via the Web Component. The issue initially occurs in the `document`, where the light DOM sits. If you want to avoid document content from showing before the shadow DOM of the Custom Element is loaded, then you will need to add a style (sheet) to tell the document what to do. The Web Component doesn't 'own' slotted content.

```
custom-select:has(:not(:defined)){
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Your explanation made perfect sense expressing it from the main document's perspective, which is what it is.  Loved that.  Regarding the code example, I think it's excessive to run an addition check with the `:has` pseudo selector, and normally I wouldn't want the light dom to show a reserved space because it could have a completely different context or even not be rendered on the page at all at first depending on the component's usages of it.  So I would like to suggest you update the code to `custom-option:not(:defined) { display: none; }`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: none;` because it is faster. And when both have issues with content shifting, and `display` is arguably worse in that regard, the faster options wins. 
But, indeed, consider what is best for your use case. 

As a side note, the upcoming `content-visibility` improves the performance even more. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content-visibility